# React -> Saving in one state only the 'id' and 'name' of the object

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Good evening, I have an objet array coming from my API, and would like to keep in one state only the 'id' and 'name' of the object. Does anybody have any idea how to do it?

```
state = {
    countries: [//{id: name}, {id: name}, {id: name}]
};
componentDidMount() {
    api.get('/countries').then(res => {
        // ??
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that the response from the API is an array of object, you can simply loop through the response to extract only the fields (`id` and `name`) that you need, and update your component's state with the new data.

```
componentDidMount() {
  api.get('/countries').then(res => {
    const countries = res.map((country) => ({
      id, name,
    }));
    this.setState({
      countries
    });
  });
}
```